# 'tree' and 'ls' change text color on Linux command line

Tags: linux, terminal, tree, ls

I've been having a peculiar issue caused by the `tree` command on Linux. When I call `tree`, the the color of the command prompt changes, and is only returned to normal by the `ls` command. I'm curious if others have encountered the same issue, and if they have fixes or workarounds. I'm using the solarized color scheme (though I'm not sure it's displaying entirely as intended) and I've confirmed that the issue arises on both xterm and gnome-terminal.

Thanks!

(Edit: I deleted the screenshot because it had some personal information)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The screenshot shows that the `tree` command is setting the foreground color, without resetting it.

The `ls` command *does* reset colors, sending

```
\e[0m
```

(where `\e` is the escape character).  Call it a bug in `tree`.  There is no general/portable method for restoring the original colors *before* a program is run.  It is each program's responsibility to reset colors.